# lifetime of a process ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, unix, time

I found a function that returns several parameters regarding the processes active on my device, between the various data I needed to know the time to use this process (or the start time), I found this information by browsing the structure back but can not extract them for use in my project

[image]

if i try with

```
int test = proc_list[i].kp_proc.p_un; //does not allow me to write __p_starttime.tv_usec
```

how can I go to use those data by placing them in a my variable with the correct format?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't compile or write that line:

```
int test = proc_list[i].kp_proc.p_un
```

is because `p_un` is a struct.  It's not an `int`.

I'm not 100% certain, but I would try this:

```
time_t seconds = proc_list[i].kp_proc.p_un.__p_starttime.tv_sec;
```

And see if you get a lifetime (returned as seconds) out of that.